# Cookies not persistent between page reloads Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

My cookies are not persistent between page reloads. I'm trying to store a cookie to save the language the user would like to view the page in. I set a variable with the abbreviation for the language and then use a lookup table to provide the right translation for various page elements. The variable is set like this:

```
var pre = $cookies.language || $locale.id.split('-')[0];
var currentLanguage = locales[pre] || 'english';
console.log('language cookie on page load is: ',$cookies.language);
// other function uses lookup table to fill in elements
```

There is some other logic in a controller that calls a function in my service. The service function changes the value stored in the cookie and reloads the page:

```
        function(language){
        $cookies.language = language;
        console.log('language cookie has been set to: ',$cookies.language);
        console.log('now reloading page');
        $window.location.reload();
        }
```

Idk much about cookies, but I'm doing all of this locally if that makes a difference. I'm loading the index.html file from the file system. The only served files would be some bootstrap and angular files from CDNs.

Comment: What version of Angular? If you're using 1.4, there's a breaking change in the `$cookies` service ~ [*"`$cookies` no longer exposes properties that represent the current browser cookie values. Now you must use the get/put/remove/etc. methods"*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Comment: @Phil right, I'm using 1.3.15 and I checked the corresponding documentation. I'm also trying to evaluate cookies in my js console and it's saying cookies are disabled for local files. Would opening the html from my file system count as being a local file and would it be the same if i served them from localhost?

Comment: That's your problem then. You will need some kind of web-server if you want to use cookies. I'd suggest using local storage instead

Comment: @Phil what do you mean by local storage? write to a file as a temporary sub for cookies?

Comment: No, as in [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: @Phil I used raw javascript to set the cookies and the angular $cookies service to read them since this app will be served in production and once i set up my local server. I tested with firefox instead of chrome and it allowed me to use cookies from local files. Thanks for the localStorage advice. Can you explain why you would use that over cookies even in production?